Excel Ribbon Key Tips activation key
For some reason unknown to me the / key is now activating the Key Tips in Excel.  This on my corporate Office 365, Excel version 2407.

From Keyboard shortcuts in Excel, the activation key stroke should be the Alt key.  This still works, and I can toggle the Key Tips on and off when using the Alt key.
But when the focus is in an empty Excel cell, pressing the / key turns the Key Tips on, however pressing it again does not toggle the Key Tips off.  And when the focus is in the edit filed for a cell, pressing / does not turn the Key Tips on (But it does for the Alt key).
When the focus is a cell which has other text in it, pressing / does result in a "/" character.
I have looked everywhere in Excel, but haven't seen anything that would trigger the behavior that I am seeing.
Where should I be looking to change this behavior so that pressing the / key in an empty cell produces a "/" character?

It almost sounds like a third party program like AutoHotkey sends the alt down if / is pressed. Can you see if this happens outside of excel?

It's definitely weird.  I don't have any third party accelerator programs (that I know of!).  Pressing / in Word and Visio doesn't activate the Key Tips, and pressing it in other programs just produces the "/" character.  Of course I am trying to enter data that starts with "/"

in Excel, you can press ALT-F11 to open Visual Basic for Applications. You can check if you have a macro there that could be responsible for this. If so, then its likely pushed by your IT department.

Okay, scratch that. I just tested this in my own excel, and it also happens here. Must be a feature or bug from Microsoft then...

I'm leaning towards "bug".  But this is changed functionality as it never used to do this.  Hmm .. maybe it's a Lotus 123 compatibility thing?

There is a simple explanation as stated here:

I do not have Excel 2016 but in earlier versions the / key was the Excel Menu Key
Delete it from the box where you see it in the snip below
in Options>Advanced

It is not a bug. I have verified the option is still present as seen on the image below when you go to File -> Options -> Advanced -> Lotus compatibility.


That's the correct answer (and I was just about to post the same as my own answer).  I deleted that "Menu key" and I am getting the expected operation.

+1 good to know

But I swear that this is changed functionality and that I have previously entered literally thousands of cells with leading "/".  Which is why things looked weird to me  today.  And it's not likely that I could accidentally change the Advanced Options.

The functionality hasn't changed; however it is entirely possible that an Office upgrade at some point "reset" this option. I used this function a lot when I just transitioned from Lotus-123 (yes, I know...)
